# How to avoid the MS Flow trigger loop?

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate

There is a trigger "Item created or Modified" and just after the trigger we are calling an action to update that item that will certainly trigger the flow and eventually it will go into loop. Please suggest a way to prevent this looping behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is known behavior for SharePoint list and [this product request](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Power-Automate-Ideas/Disable-Event-Firing-when-Flow-updates-a-SharePoint-list-item/idi-p/100399/page/8#comments) got declined as well. Normally we will have update trigger for any database table and filtering attributes to decide the scenario, in addition have to avoid updating the same attribute again in that transaction.

What you can do is, keep a hidden column in the list, to check and stop the infinite loop like discussed in [community thread](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/General-Power-Automate/Update-Item-Infinite-Loop/m-p/252742)